# Django: Getting image urls as list

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to get image url as list. it is possible to get image url using `imageFieldObject.url`.

Can the same be retrieved using like `values_list("imageFieldObject__url")` or something?

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
     imageFieldObject = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could get all image field paths by:

`urls_list = [MEDIA_URL + image_path for image_path in SampleModel.objects.values_list('imageFieldObj', flat=True)]`

Comment: i need full absolute url. like what imageFieldObject.url() returns

Comment: you can build it, how does your program create a full url? i think it just uses `MEDIA_URL`

Comment: <img class="user_image" src="{{ item.imageFieldObject.url }} this returns full url right and i am not concatenating it to media url

Comment: @AromalSasidharan, i hope someone has a better way, but for the most part, concating the MEDIA_URL and the path is all that is happeninging when you call the `url` method of your image object https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/storage.py#L269

Comment: what i mean is that, i want only imageFieldObject column as list of absolute urls from views.